# How to navigate from a fragment to another clearing some other fragments from the stack?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have the following navigation graph

```
Frag A  -->  Frag B --> Frag C --> -->  Frag D
        \                            /
         ->  Frag E  <---------------
                     \
                      -> Frag F
```

My current stack is [Frag A, Frag B, Frag C and **Frag D**]. Knowing that my current destination is Frag D and that I want to navigate from Frag D to Frag E clearing Frag B, Frag C and Frag D from the stack, how can one do it?

---

Current stack: [Frag A, Frag B, Frag C and **Frag D**]

Intent: navigate to Frag E clearing [Frag B, Frag C and Frag D] from the stack

resulting stack: [Frag A and **Frag E**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are navigating through navigation graph actions, that would be an easy task by specifying that you need your action to popUpTo certain fragment like this :

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/D_Frag"
        ...           
            <action
            android:id="@+id/action_DFrag_To_EFrag"
            app:destination="@+id/E_Frag"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/B_Frag"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            />
        ...
    </fragment>
```

where `popUpToInclusive` flag means (do you want to popUpTo B_Frag including B_Frag(True) or excluding it(False)).

this action will pop all fragments from top stack until it reaches B_Frag, and then go the destination E_Frag.

and by

> navigating through navigation graph actions

I mean that you use likes of this code line in D Fragment to navigate

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(DFrag.this)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_DFrag_To_EFrag);
```

**N.B** : three dots in code (...) means I don't care what code is written there and you may delete the three dots and include whatever you want